# How to concatenate different layer outputs to feed as input to a new layer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation, layer

I am new in Tensorflow and Python. I have built a multi layer network and I have pretrained it. Now I want to build another multilayer network next to the first. The weights of the first network are frozen and I want to concatenate features I got from the first network with the normal input of the layer of the new network. How can I concatenate the output of a specific layer in the first network with the input to this network and feed the layer of the new network?

Comment: Can you please clarify the requirement? Can you add a pseudo code for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the simple example of concatenating 2 input layers of different input shape and feeding to next layer.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, concatenate, Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adagrad

input_img1 = Input(shape=(44,44,3))
x1 = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img1)

input_img2 = Input(shape=(34,34,3))
x2 = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img2)
# Zero Padding of 5 at the top, bottom, left and right side of an image tensor
x3 = ZeroPadding2D(padding = (5,5))(x2)

# Concatenate works as layers have same size output
x4 = concatenate([x1,x3])

output = Dense(18, activation='relu')(x4)

model = Model(inputs=[input_img1,input_img2], outputs=output)

model.summary()
```

Output -

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 34, 34, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 44, 44, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 34, 34, 3)    84          input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 44, 44, 3)    84          input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPadding2D (None, 44, 44, 3)    0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 44, 44, 6)    0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 zero_padding2d_1[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 44, 44, 18)   126         concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 294
Trainable params: 294
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

If the above answer is not what you are looking for, then would request you to share the pseudo code or flow diagram of the models to answer better.

Comment: Yes, I have also found this way to implement it and it worked. However, thanks a lot for the reply!!!